# I am trying to make a search box like that of google in php but

Tags: php, html, css

I am trying to make a search box like that of google in php but I do not know how to make it drop down instead of echoing the results at the top-left of the page.

code PHP:

```
$output = " ";
//collect
if(isset($_POST['searchbox'])){
    $searchq = $_POST['searchbox'];
    $query = DB::query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username LIKE '%$searchq%'");
    $count = count($searchq);

    if(strlen($searchq) == 0 && $searchq!=$query){
        $output .= "No such user";
        echo $output;
    }else{
        foreach($query as $row){
            $userq = $row['username'];

            $output .= '<div style="position:relative;""><a href="profile.php?username='.$userq.'">'.$userq.'</a></div>';
            echo $output;
        }
    }
}
```

Code html:

```
<input type="text" name="searchbox" class="search" placeholder="Search">
    <input type="submit"  value=">>">
```

Comment: Do not use not validated user input in a SQL query please.

Comment: Your code is at a really high risk of SQL injection. Right now, we could delete your whole database in a few seconds without any need of deeper knowledge of your system. Please visit http://bobby-tables.com and learn about prepared statements and how to use them. Make sure you **always** use them when querying the database with **user inputs**

Comment: Well, the correct way would be going a complete different way. Since you want the results instantly and not after a page reload, you probally should just write a small api for it that just returns an JSON string back with the information and use AJAX on the frontend. With the results you got you now can use the javascript methods for adding additional dropdown values. Of course you have to code that too or download existing codes. If you don't care about crossbrowser support, you can also use [HTML datalist](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist).

Comment: Take a reading delve into [jQuery UI Autocomplete](https://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) ... it will do what you are looking for.